# How to patch configmap in json file with kustomize?

Tags: kubernetes, configmap, kustomize

How to patch "db.password" in the following cm with kustomize?

comfigmap:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  dbp.conf: |-
    {
      "db_properties": {
        "db.driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "db.password": "123456",
        "db.user": "root"
      }
    }

kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels: {}
  name: dbcm
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create new file with updated values and use command replace along wih create

```
kubectl create configmap NAME --from-file file.name -o yaml --dry-run | kubectl replace -f -
```

Comment: thanks, I need to patch it with kustomize. just like patch yaml file.

Comment: if you have file with you can update the file value and run kubectl apply command it will replace existing value in configmap.

Comment: op asked about kustomize and not kubectl way of patching cm.

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/680

Comment: https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/issues/3787

Answer (score 1):

create a placeholder in your file and replace it with real data while applying kustomize

your code will be like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
sed -i "s/PLACE-HOLDER/123456/g" db_config.yaml
kustomize config.yaml >> kustomizeconfig.yaml
kubectl apply -f kustomizeconfig.yaml -n foo
```

And the db_config file will be:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  dbp.conf: |-
    {
      "db_properties": {
        "db.driver": "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver",
        "db.password": "PLACE_HODLER",
        "db.user": "root"
      }
    }

kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  labels: {}
  name: dbcm
```

NB: This should be running on the pipeline to have the config file cloned from repo, so the real file won't be updated.